# Apple Watch Glance – Load Data with NSURL

Tags: swift, watchkit, nsurl, watchos-2, apple-watch-glances

I am creating a glance and need to load some data from an API. I have written the following code but it does not allow me to asynchronously or synchronously request data in the glance controller.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
    print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
}
```

The error occurs on `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest` and says `sendAsynchronousRequest(_:queue:completionHandler:) is unavailable`. I remember that have read somewhere that you should not load data in a glance, and if this is the case how should I load the data each time the glance appears?

**My questions are:**

**How can I load data over HTTP in a apple watch glance?  And if it is impossible to load HTTP data in a glance, how else should I do it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` should work, but since it is deprecated, I would recommend using `NSURLSession` instead.

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    // handle the response
}
task.resume()
```

A good place to call it is the `awakeWithContext` method of your glances interface controller. I have done it and it works fine on a glance.